# To check if an xml is read by any process

Tags: xml, http

I have an xml file. I want to check if any process(http request) is calling/reading my XML file. How is that possible.

Comment: You'll have to do that on server side and it will depend on what you are running there. Likely you'll have to build some kind of a custom handler that logs when a resource is accessed